# set a price to a var JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to make a GUI where a user can chose a weapon by category with a price and easy add more if he want.

This works but I don't know how to add a price to "conf_pistols" for each weapon which will be automatically updated if you change the weapon in the dropdown.

```js
var conf_pistols = {
  "PISTOL": "Pistol",
  "PISTOL50": "Heavy Pistol"
};
var $pistolselect = $('#optgroup_pistol');
$.each(conf_pistols, function(key, value) {
  var $option = $("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value[0]
  }, );
  $pistolselect.append($option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="weapon_class">Waffenauswahl</label>
<select id="weapon_class" name="weapon_class" class="select_weapon">
  <option value="-1"></option>
  <optgroup id="optgroup_pistol" label="Pistolen">

  </optgroup>
</select>
<div id="weapon_cash" class="pa_cash">
  <p id="weapon_cash_sum" class="pa_cash_sum">0 $</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should the content of `conf_pistols` be updated when the dropdown is changed?

Comment: Make `conf_pistols` an array of "weapons" -> `conf_pistols = [ { type: "Pistol", price: 4.5 }, { ... }, ... ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the price to your obejct

```js
const conf_pistols = {
  "PISTOL": {
    "name": "Pistol",
    "price": 50
  },
  "PISTOL50": {
    "name": "Heavy Pistol",
    "price": 500
  }
};
var $pistolselect = $('#optgroup_pistol');
$.each(conf_pistols, function(key, value) {
  var $option = $("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value.name
  }, );
  $pistolselect.append($option);
});
$("#weapon_class").on("change",function() {
  $("#weapon_cash_sum").text(conf_pistols[this.value].price)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="weapon_class">Waffenauswahl</label>
<select id="weapon_class" name="weapon_class" class="select_weapon">
  <option value="-1"></option>
  <optgroup id="optgroup_pistol" label="Pistolen">

  </optgroup>
</select>
<div id="weapon_cash" class="pa_cash">
  <p id="weapon_cash_sum" class="pa_cash_sum">0 $</p>
</div>
```